# what should i do to solve this error in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I'm doing my coding in solidity while coding , I'm getting this error as follow;

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

at the highlighted line I got the problem.

[image: This is the code]

Kindly let me know what to do.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, the code in text form, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it an error, or just a warning? From the looks of it, you've just created a variable that you do not use. And the program is letting you know through this warning.

Warnings are technically harmless, and they shouldn't prevent your program from running, but the warning does reminds you about this unused line in case you're missing something out. If that's not the case, you can either ignore it or delete that line of code.

It is possible that the program will already give you warnings before you've even finished your bit of code. That behaviour is normal, as they like to be pre-cautious. In that case, you can just ignore it and continue your coding until the variable is used, then the warning will disappear on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just activated auto compiled

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).